# Show that $\lim_{x\to 4} \sqrt{x} = 2$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Show that $\lim_{x\to 4} \sqrt{x} = 2$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit.

**Method 1**

Let $\epsilon>0$

Choose $\delta<\epsilon-6$. ($\delta>0$)

If $|x-4|<\delta \implies -\delta < x-4 < \delta \implies 4-\delta<x<4+\delta$,

then, $|\sqrt{x}-2| < \sqrt{x}+2 < \sqrt{4+\delta}+2 < 6+\delta < \epsilon$

Hence, by $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit, $\lim_{x\to 4} \sqrt{x} = 2$

**Is method 1 correct?**

**Method 2**

Let $\epsilon>0$

Choose $\delta<$___. ($\delta>0$)

If $|x-4|<\delta \implies -\delta < x-4 < \delta \implies 4-\delta<x<4+\delta$,

then, $|\sqrt{x}-2| < \sqrt{x}+2 < \sqrt{4+\delta}+2$

(Scratch work: $\sqrt{4+\delta}+2=\epsilon \implies \delta+4=(\epsilon-2)^{2} \implies \delta=\epsilon^{2}-4\epsilon$.)

Now I'm tempted to fill the blank by choosing $\delta<\epsilon^{2}-4\epsilon$. But when I do that I'm not getting the desired $|\sqrt{x}-2| < \epsilon$ because $\sqrt{4+\delta}+2<\sqrt{4+\epsilon^{2}-4\epsilon}+2=\sqrt{(\epsilon-2)^{2}}+2=|\epsilon-2|+2$, which is not necessarily less than $\epsilon$.

**What's wrong in method 2?**

Comment: Your $\delta$ in method 2 doesn't work, as $\delta > 0$ if and only if $\varepsilon \geq 4$.

Comment: Method 1 doesn't make sense to me.  $\delta$ should not be negative, but if $\varepsilon$ is small, it will be.  Also, `$\epsilon$-$\delta$`.  That is a hyphen, not a subtraction.

Comment: @stange True, I see the contradiction. So where have I gone wrong in the procedure? Which step has caused the contradiction?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Agreed. But can you tell me which step contributed to the contradiction?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser Right at the beginning, you chose a $\delta$ which makes no sense!  Everything after that is necessarily wrong.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Usually, I write these proofs backward. Like I leave space for delta in the beginning and then proceed with $|f(x)-l|$ to come up with an expression in delta which is then equated to $\epsilon$. That's how I arrived at $\delta<\epsilon-6$

Comment: $|\sqrt x - 2| <\sqrt x +2$ is not going to do you any good.  The thing is you need to deal with $\sqrt x$ getting close to $2$ and pinning $|\sqrt x -2|$ to be sqeezed into a very small space.  Choosing something big, such as $\sqrt x + 2$ simply *because* it is big and you can rattle $\sqrt x - 2$ safely in it, is doomed to fail as the whole point is to step in and get as close as you can under a microscope and *NOT* to step back far enough that you can side step it.  This will simply not work.  ever.

Comment: "Usually, I write these proofs backward." then write it backward.  If $|\sqrt x - 2| < \epsilon$ the $-\epsilon < \sqrt x-2< \epsilon$ and $2-\epsilon < \sqrt x < 2+\epsilon$ and if we make the assumption $\epsilon < 2$ (which we can as we want $\epsilon$ to be *small*), we get $(2-\epsilon)^2 < x < (2+\epsilon)^2$ .  Use *that* to find $\delta$.

Comment: @fleablood "Choosing something big, such as $\sqrt{x} + 2$ simply because it is big and you can rattle $\sqrt{x}-2$ safely in it, is doomed to fail" --- Thanks for pointing this out. This precisely was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Scratch Work

The goal is to determine a value of $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-4| < \delta$ implies that $|\sqrt{x} - 2| < \varepsilon$.  Note

$$ \bigl| x-4 \bigr| = \bigl| (\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+2) \bigr|. \label{eq1}\tag{*}$$

Observe that $| x-4 | < \delta$ implies
\begin{align}
-\delta < x-4 < \delta &\iff 4-\delta < x < 4+\delta \\
&\iff \sqrt{4-\delta} < \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{4+\delta} \\
&\iff \sqrt{4-\delta}+2 < \sqrt{x}+2 < \sqrt{4+\delta}+2.
\end{align}
Hence $\sqrt{x}+2$ it is possible to conclude that $\sqrt{x}+2 > 2$ for any value of $\delta$ such that $\sqrt{4-\delta}$ "makes sense", i.e. $\delta < 4$.  This provides some control over the second factor in (\ref{eq1}) (it will be bigger than $1$, which is helpful).  The other factor is $\sqrt{x}-2$, which is the thing we are trying to make small.  In particular,
$$\bigl| \sqrt{x}-2 \bigr| < \bigl| (\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+2) \bigr| = \bigl| x-4\bigr| < \delta. $$
Of particular note is that $|\sqrt{x}-2|$ is now bounded by $\delta$, which is exactly what is desired, as long as $\delta < \varepsilon$.

So choose $\delta$ to be smaller than $4$ (to bound $\sqrt{x}+2$), and smaller than $\varepsilon$ (to get the desired result in the end).

##### Proof

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta < \min\{4, \varepsilon\}$.  Suppose that $|x-4| < \delta$.  Since $\delta < 4$, if $|x-4|<\delta$, then
$$ |x-4| < 4 \implies 0 < x \implies 2 < \sqrt{x}+2. $$
In particular, $\sqrt{x}+2 > 1$, hence
\begin{align}
\bigl|\sqrt{x} - 2\bigr|
&< \bigl| (\sqrt{x}+2)(\sqrt{x}-2)\bigr| && \text{(since $\sqrt{x}+2 > 1$)} \\
&= \bigl| x-4 \bigr| \\
&< \delta \\
&< \varepsilon,
\end{align}
which is the desired result.

Comment: Understood. I think where I went wrong is that the way I manipulated the expression $|\sqrt{x}-2$ and the desired inequation, I ended up getting the expression $\sqrt{4+\delta}+2$, which can't be in any way equated to $\epsilon$ because of the $+2$ term.

Comment: So far as I can tell @Curiouserandcuriouser you never tried to compare $\sqrt x$ to $x$ in any direct and/or meaningful way.

Comment: But what's the need for considering $\delta$ to be less than $4$? Isn't $\sqrt{x}+2$ always greater than 1, as the domain and range of $\sqrt{x}$ is all real numbers greater than or equal to zero?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser If $\delta > 4$, then $\sqrt{4-\delta}$ is not a real number.  I want to restrict my variables to being real.  It is a somewhat pedantic constraint, but it is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Another possible approach. Let $|x - 4| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Then one concludes that:
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{x} - 2| = \frac{|x - 4|}{\sqrt{x} + 2} < \frac{|x - 4|}{2} < \frac{\delta_{\varepsilon}}{2} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: This approach seems to be pretty efficient. So choosing a $\delta$ that is less than $2\varepsilon$ is enough for the proof to work? Or should it be $\min\{4, 2\varepsilon\}$?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser it suffices to consider $\delta_{\varepsilon} < 2\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, both your methods are wrong due to a wrong choice of $\delta$. One thing I find helpful when trying to proof these kind of limits is to choose multiple $\delta$ for different cases and then take the minimal $\delta$. So in your example, take $|\sqrt{x}-2|$. You have shown already, that $4-\delta<x<4+\delta$ for any choice of $\delta$. There are two cases to consider:

1.$|\sqrt{x}-2|=\sqrt{x}-2<\sqrt{(\epsilon+2)^2}-2=\epsilon$, as $\epsilon>0$, so $\epsilon+2>0$ with $\delta = (\epsilon+2)^2-4(>0)$.
2.$|\sqrt{x}-2|=2-\sqrt{x}<2-\sqrt{4-\delta}$ If you assume $0<4-\delta$, which you are allowed to. Now you can calculate from $2-\sqrt{4-\delta}\leq\epsilon$ that $0<4-(2-\epsilon)^2\leq\delta$.
By taking $\delta_m=\min\{((\epsilon+2)^2-4,4-(2-\epsilon)^2,4\}$ you get all the desired inequalities and have proven your limit.

Comment: Understood most of it. But why did you take $\delta_m=\min\{((\epsilon+2)^2-4,4-(2-\epsilon)^2,4\}$? I mean, why was $4$ inside the bracket? Why $\delta_m=\min\{((\epsilon+2)^2-4,4-(2-\epsilon)^2\}$ wasn't enough?

Comment: I assumed $0<4-\delta$ so I can take the square root of that expression, which is equivalent to $\delta<4$

Comment: technically you would have to provide a different $\delta$ for the case of $4-(2-\epsilon)^2$ being negative as well, but as we are interested in small, not big, values of $\epsilon$ you are usually allowed to make the assumption of $\epsilon$ being arbitrarily small.