# Given $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^2+2 \sqrt{x}}$, How to prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} f(x)$ using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I was wondering how I could use the limit of a function definition to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} f(x) = 1/4$, where $f$ is defined as $$f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^2+2 \sqrt{x}}.$$ Here's some work so far.

$$\left| \frac{x+1}{x^2+2 \sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{4} \right| \leq \frac{\left| x+1 \right|}{ \left| x^2 + 2 \sqrt{x}\right|} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{\left|x-4\right| + 3}{\left|x^2 + 2 \sqrt x \right|} + \frac{1}{4}$$

Suppose we let $\delta_1 = 5$, so that $1 < \left|x\right| < 9$ and $3 < 2 \sqrt{|x|} + |x|^2 < 87$. Can I say that $$ < \frac{\delta + 3}{3} + \frac{1}{4} $$ and for any $\varepsilon$, choose $\delta = \min ( 5, (12 \varepsilon - 15)/4 )$ to satisfy $0 < |x-4| < \delta$ and $|f(x)-1/4| < \varepsilon$? Also, should I mention that $\delta$ should be chosen so that itself and $\varepsilon$ is greater than 0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your question in the post.

Comment: Your first inequality is valid, but not helpful. You would then need to make $\frac{\left| x+1 \right|}{ \left| x^2 + 2 \sqrt{x}\right|} + \frac{1}{4} < \varepsilon$, but the left hand side is at least $\frac{1}{4}$, so you'll fail for every $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{4}$. Try, instead, to simplify $\frac{x+1}{x^2+2 \sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{4}$ into a single fraction, and maybe rationalise the denominator.

Comment: The inequality $|x-y| \leq |x| + |y|$ is useless here. I had asked a similar question here. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863533/show-that-lim-x-to-4-sqrtx-2-using-epsilon-delta-definition-of-l

Comment: Thank you for clarifying on why we can't have epsilon in the form $\delta$ plus some constant. It makes sense since we're saying "for all epsilon", but what is the constant was negative? Would it apply to all positive epsilons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have\begin{align}|f(x)-f(4)|&=\left|\frac{x+1}{x^2+2\sqrt x}-\frac14\right|\\&=\frac{\left|4-2\sqrt x+4x-x^2\right|}{4(x^2+2\sqrt x)}\\&=\frac{\left|4-2\sqrt x+4x-16-x^2+16\right|}{4(x^2+2\sqrt x)}\\&\leqslant\frac{2\left|\sqrt x-2\right|+4|x-4|+|x^2-16|}{4(x^2+2\sqrt x)}\\&=\frac{2\frac{|x-4|}{\sqrt x+2}+4|x-4|+|x+4||x-4|}{4(x^2+2\sqrt x)}\\&=\frac{2\frac1{\sqrt x+2}+4+|x+4|}{4(x^2+2\sqrt x)}|x-4|.\end{align}Now, suppose that $|x-4|<3$. Then $x>1$, and therefore$$x^2+2\sqrt x>3\quad\text{and}\quad\sqrt x+2>3.$$On the other hand, $x<7$, and therefore $|x+4|<11$. So,\begin{align}\frac{2\frac1{\sqrt x+2}+4+|x+4|}{4(x^2+2\sqrt x)}&<\frac{2/3+15}{12}\\&<2.\end{align}Therefore, given $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta=\min\left\{3,\frac{\varepsilon}2\right\}$, then, when $|x-4|<\delta$, you have\begin{align}|f(x)-f(4)|&\leqslant\frac{2\frac1{\sqrt x+2}+4+|x+4|}{4(x^2+2\sqrt x)}|x-4|\\&<2\times\frac\varepsilon2\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: Can we also go this route: say that $|x-4|<5$, meaning
$$\left|\frac{4x + 4 - x^2 - 2 \sqrt{x}}{4(x^2 + 2 \sqrt{x})}\right| = \frac{|x-4|}{4} \left|\frac{x + 2/(2+\sqrt x)}{x^2 + 2 \sqrt x}\right| < \delta/4 \left(\frac{9+2/3}{3}\right)$$. Choose $\delta = \min \{5, \frac{12 \varepsilon}{9+2/3}\}$ to satisfy the definition?

Comment: That doesn't work. If $|x-4|<5$, then $x$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$, and therefore you cannot possibly have$$\left|\frac{x+2/(2+\sqrt x)}{x^2+2\sqrt x}\right|<\frac{9+2/3}3.$$

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that before. 3 is easier to work with because x would never be that close to zero. I was thinking, though, that since $-1 < x < 9$, then $1 < |x| < 9$. What is incorrect with this thinking?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $a<b\implies|a|<|b|$, which is false; just take $a=-2$ and $b=1$.

Comment: @nemmie Take $x=0$ in your example.